# Looking for a trailing $ sign using Regex

Tags: regex

The pattern I'm looking for looks like `$guid1$` with the `$` signs on each side. Unfortunately, my regex in `grep` (and probably elsewhere) interprets that last $ as something else.

`"\$guid[0-9]\$"` works but `"\$guid[0-9]\$"` does not. What can I do?

Comment: The regex itself is fine (it does match), I would say that this is a program setting, or some different kind of function needs to be used.

Comment: I was also using it in sed. I believe the answer is actually \\\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around your regex:

```
grep '\$guid1\$' file
```

OR use `fgrep` for fixed string search:

```
fgrep '$guid1$' file
```